# Should I give my iTunes Connect credentials to my developer?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

so I hired a developer on an online platform and he has made for me a game and now has to upload to my iTunes Connect account. But he says that he needs my credentials, because I am an individual and I cannot add him as a developer and so he cannot make a certificate for the app….

Comment: get the code from him, compile and resubmit it yourself. I don't get it?

Comment: Just need to create the cert for him in the developer portal, then revoke it after he provide u the IPA

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic/